# How to display git ls-file result in a tree-like format?

Tags: git

Let's say I have a git repo which output with tree is:

```
.                                                                                                                                                                                  
├── .gitignore                                                                   
├── untracked-file                                                                                                  
├── rep1                                                                                                                                                                           
│   └── tracked-file1                                                                                                                                                                      
├── rep2                                                                                                                                                                           
│   └── repb                                                                                                                                                                       
│       └── tracked-file2                                                                                                                                                                  
└── rep3                                                                                                                                                                           
    └── ignored-file
```

And `.gitignore` with `rep3/ignored-file`.

`git ls-files` output will be:

```
rep1/tracked-file1
rep2/repb/tracked-file2
```

How can I have:

```
.
├── .gitignore
├── rep1
│   └── file1
└── rep2
    └── repb
        └── file2
```

Instead ?

I think this is a good start:

```
tree -P <(git ls-files | tr '\n' '|')
```

Since `-P` means only list following pattern but I don't know how to add parenthesis to this one.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like the [gitree](https://github.com/jpwilliams/gitree) utility (c/o creator [jpwilliams](https://github.com/jpwilliams)) might fit the bill. (I concede that this does, however, require using another 3rd party tool.)

Similarly, this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48641100/7340562) points to using a different tool: [tree-extended](https://github.com/rulyotano/tree-extended) (c/o creator [rulyotano](https://github.com/rulyotano)).